# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I am getting an internal server error on my website. I have checked the Apache error log and found the following errors:-

> [Mon Feb 22 14:34:36.065540 2016] [core:error] [pid 660170] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59213] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Here I am pasting my .htaccess file:-

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(import.php) $1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(phpinfo.php) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(robots.txt) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(index.html) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ajax/(.*) ajax/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*) css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^data/(.*) data/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^kmz/(.*) kmz/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*) js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^dlib/(.*) dlib/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^java/(.*) java/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^flash/(.*) flash/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^export/(.*) export/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^editor.php(.*) editor.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^config.php(.*) config.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin.php(.*) admin.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ajax.php(.*) ajax.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*) index.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^info.php util.php?um=info&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^util.php(.*) util.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ux/([^/]*)/([^/^=]*)/(.*) util.php?um=$1&mode=$2&$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^ux/([^/]*)/(.*) util.php?um=$1&$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^ux/(.*) util.php?um=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*).html index.php?md=$1&ref=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*).html index.php?md=page&ref=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?md=page&ref=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^rss/events util.php?um=rss&ref=Events&_m=EVNT [L]
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]*) index.php?md=url&ref=$1 [L]
```

The problem started when I upgraded my PHP from 5.4 to 5.5.
Can somebody help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule` and not for all the `RewriteRule` in your .htaccess. That said you have many do-nothing rules that should also be removed. Also rather than `%{QUERY_STRING}` you can use `QSA` flag.

Try this in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]    

RewriteRule ^info\.php$ util.php?um=info [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^ux/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)$ util.php?um=$1&mode=$2&$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^ux/([^/]+)/(.*)$ util.php?um=$1&$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^ux/(.*)$ util.php?um=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ index.php?md=$1&ref=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php?md=page&ref=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?md=page&ref=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^rss/events util.php?um=rss&ref=Events&_m=EVNT [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?md=url&ref=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Another issue.The login screen is not working as expected. If I supply the login details  it returns to the login screen with the fields cleared with the browser adrs bar only showing *util.php *(login screen is run from this screen). If u manually go admin.php at this stage then u find that it has logged in bt, obviously, the transfer didn't happen properly.

Comment: The reason for this appears to be that, in the original URL of http://www.domain.co/ux/login/dest=/admin.php&mr=--&e=28 the /admin.php part hasn't been correctly sent through via one of the ux rules in .htaccess. The original rule that was handling this was:

RewriteRule ^ux/([^/]*)/([^/^=]*)/(.*) util.php?um=$1&mode=$2&$3 [L]

[ Comments separated due to character limit ]

Comment: You can revert back that rule to original one but I don't understand `domain.co/ux/login/dest=/admin.php&mr=--&e=28` URL. Strange case because you have `=` without `?`

Comment: The RewriteRule is converting
/ux/login/dest=/admin.php&mr=--&e=28
into
util.php?um=login&dest=/admin.php&mr=--&e=28

which is why that "=" is there. Basically, what's happening is that the
*ux* part is indicating that a utilty file must be called, the utility
to be called is between the next pair of /slashes/ (so, it's the login
utility in this case) and then anything after that is pushed through as is.